# Can you identify this probably-stolen BMX I paid $15 for?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

I have purchased this BMX bicycle for $15 USD.  Can somebody please tell what kind of BMX this is and if I got a good deal?

Comment: Why can't you ask the seller for more information?  I'd be worried you have just bought stolen goods (as in pinched, not the brand "stolen" )

Comment: I tried to fix your lazy screenshot of of bad photo but there are limits. Please provide a better photo. Also, for $15... it's stolen. No question at all.

Comment: Buying stolen bikes encourages bike theft. Please do not buy stolen bikes (or any other goods) ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thats a pretty bad photo, but I can see its got

- a potts mod for the front brake, where the cable passes down through the steerer of the fork.
- a detangler for the rear brake.

These allow the front wheel/bars to rotate completely in any direction with no tangling of brake cables.

The front axle pegs (foot things) suggest its a tricks or stunt bike.

The paint job looks amateur, and will have covered up decals and other identifying marks.

Those cranks look really long too, freakishly out of proportion to the rest of the bike.

Comment: Not a great answer, but better photos would help.